# JAVA SPRING rest app is receiving null in body

Tags: angular, spring

I´m building an application with Postgree, JavaSpring and Angular. `GET` requests are working correctly and I can see the propper data in Angular, but when I `POST` any data, it is saying that all the fields from my Json are `NULL` when they arrive to Java´s application controller.

Is an obvious error in my code below?

Java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp) {
        EmployeeService.insertEmployee(emp);
    }
```

Angular:

```
 async createNewUser( email, password, name, surname ) {
    let id : string;
    let body : Object;
    id = name[0] + surname[0] + (Date.now() + Math.floor((Math.random()*1000))).toString();

    body = new Object ( {

        "EmployeeEmail" :email,
        "EmployeePassword" :password,
       " EmployeeName" : name,
        "EmployeeSurname" : surname,
        "EmployeeId" : id
      });


   return await axios.post(this.apiUrl + 'createEmployee', body)
```

CLASS EMPLOYEE

```
      package com.sample.postgress.entity;

      import java.util.Date;
      import java.util.List;

      import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
      import javax.persistence.FetchType;
      import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
      import javax.persistence.MapsId;
      import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
      import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

      import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;


       public class Employee extends UserPacman {

        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
        @MapsId("UserPacmanId")
        @JoinColumn(name="UserPacmanId", nullable=false)
          UserPacman userpacman;

        @OneToMany(targetEntity = EmployeeProjectPeriod.class, 
          cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="EmployeeId")
        @JsonIgnoreProperties("Employee")
        List<EmployeeProjectPeriod>EmployeeProjects;

        @OneToMany(targetEntity = Absence.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="EmployeeId")
        @JsonIgnoreProperties("Employee")
        List<Absence>EmployeeAbsence;


        @OneToMany(targetEntity = Skill.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="EmployeeId")
        @JsonIgnoreProperties("Employee")



       public int getHireData() {
       return hireData;
       }


       public void setHireData(int hireData) {
       this.hireData = hireData;
       }


       private int hireData ;




      }
```

CLASS USERPACMAN

```
     package com.sample.postgress.entity;
     import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
     import javax.persistence.Entity;
     import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
     import javax.persistence.Table;


     @Entity
     @Table
      public class UserPacman {

      String UserPacmanId;
      String UserPacmanName;
      String UserPacmanSurname;
      String UserPacmanEmail;
      String UserPacmanPassword;

       @OneToOne(mappedBy="UserPacman", cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
        Employee employee;




      public String getUserPacmanSurname() {
            return UserPacmanSurname;
          }
       public void setUserPacmanSurname(String UserPacmanSurname) {
    this.UserPacmanSurname = UserPacmanSurname;
    }
      public String getUserPacmanEmail() {
          return UserPacmanEmail;
     }
      public void setUserPacmanEmail(String UserPacmanEmail) {
        this.UserPacmanEmail = UserPacmanEmail;
      }
      public String getUserPacmanId() {
          return UserPacmanId;
       }
      public void setUserPacmanId(String UserPacmanId) {
        this.UserPacmanId = UserPacmanId;
       }
      public String getUserPacmanName() {
         return UserPacmanName;
       }
      public void setUserPacmanName(String UserPacmanName) {
         this.UserPacmanName = UserPacmanName;
      }
       public String getUserPacmanPassword() {
         return UserPacmanPassword;
       }
       public void setUserPacmanPassword(String UserPacmanPassword) {
         this.UserPacmanPassword = UserPacmanPassword;
       }


       }
```

APPLICATIONCONTROLLER

```
       package com.sample.postgress.controller;

       import java.util.List;

        import javax.annotation.Resource;

        import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

         import com.sample.postgress.entity.Absence;
         import com.sample.postgress.entity.Employee;
         import com.sample.postgress.entity.Project;
          import com.sample.postgress.entity.Skill;
        import com.sample.postgress.entity.UserPacman;
         import com.sample.postgress.service.AbsenceService;
          import com.sample.postgress.service.EmployeeService;
        import com.sample.postgress.service.ProjectService;
        import com.sample.postgress.service.SkillService;
        import com.sample.postgress.service.UserPacmanService;


        @RestController
        @RequestMapping("/postgressApp")
        @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200") 

        public class ApplicationController {
        @Resource
        SkillService SkillService;
        @Resource 
        ProjectService ProjectService;
        @Resource 
         EmployeeService EmployeeService;
        @Resource 
        UserPacmanService UserPacmanService;
        @Resource
        AbsenceService AbsenceService;

        @GetMapping(value = "/SkillList")
         public List<Skill> getSkill() {
             return SkillService.findAll();

         }

        @PostMapping(value = "/createSkill")
       public void createSkill(@RequestBody Skill  pro ) {
         SkillService.insertSkill(pro);

          }
          @PutMapping(value = "/updateSkill")
           public void updateSkill(@RequestBody Skill pro) {
           SkillService.updateSkill(pro);

          }

          @PutMapping(value = "/executeSkill")
           public void executeUpdateSkill(@RequestBody Skill pro) {
           SkillService.executeUpdateSkill(pro);

            }


           @GetMapping(value = "/EmployeeList")
             public List<Employee> getEmployee() {
           return EmployeeService.findAll();

            }
            @GetMapping(value = "/ProjectList")
             public List<Project> getProject() {
             return ProjectService.findAll();

             }




        @DeleteMapping(value = "/deleteProjectById")
         public void deleteProject(@RequestBody Project pro) {
          ProjectService.deleteProject(pro);

         }


        @RequestMapping(value = "/createEmployee", method = 
         RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
         public void createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp) {
         EmployeeService.insertEmployee(emp);

       }
```

Here is, in applicationController where it receives all the object´s fields null

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer without you posting your code.

Comment: There is the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the information you provided, your employee object has this properties?

```
"EmployeeEmail",
"EmployeePassword",
" EmployeeName" ,
"EmployeeSurname",
"EmployeeId"
```

maybe you create an Employee object with different field names: like "email", "password" and so on?

Comment: Actually the Employee class has heritage from a class called userpacman

Comment: the names of the given fields have to be equal to your implementation in order to parse the body automatically to an object.